# How to render ChartJs with Kotlin React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

I am experimenting with a simple project based with Kotlin and React and I have some data I would like to visualise with ChartJs. 
But I am not sure how exactly to 'connect the dots'.

I am randomly generating some data in background about some dummy 'customers'. It is a continuous `stream` of data (technically it goes on forever if I don't stop it) and it looks like this:

```
data:{"name":"John","age": 22,"money":1088.434131568658585820230655372142791748046875}
data:{"name":"Patric","age": 32,"money":9803.739582599226196180097758769989013671875}
data:{"name":"Sven","age": 13,"money":6654.2184028105320976465009152889251708984375}
data:{"name":"Trevor","age": 29,"money":1818.314185601747112741577439010143280029296875}
data:{"name":"John","age": 30,"money":427.240483111973617269541136920452117919921875}
data:{"name":"Mark","age": 15,"money":3065.9830877835693172528408467769622802734375}
data:{"name":"Daniel","age": 18,"money":5860.1371074951812261133454740047454833984375}
data:{"name":"Chris","age": 28,"money":7547.2329861790212817140854895114898681640625}
```

Here is my Model:

```
data class CustomerData(var name: String, var age: Int, var money: Int)
```

and my Chart Component:

```
interface CustomerChartProps : RProps {
    var customerDataList: List<CustomerData>
}

interface CustomerChartState : RState {
    var customerDataList: List<CustomerData>
}

class CustomerChart : RComponent<CustomerChartProps, CustomerChartState>() {

    override fun CustomerChartState.init(props: CustomerChartProps) {
        customerDataList = props.customerDataList
    }

    override fun RBuilder.render() {
        canvas() {
            attrs.id = "myChart"
            attrs.height = "600"
            attrs.width = "600"
            key = "chart"

            div {
                props.customerDataList
            }


        }

        var chart = document.getElementById("myChart")
    }
}

fun dummyChartData(data: List<CustomerData>) =
        listOf(CustomerData("John", 30, 9999))

fun RBuilder.customerChart(customerDataList: List<CustomerData>) = child(CustomerChart::class) {
    attrs.customerDataList = customerDataList
}
```

What is not clear is how do I tell the `RState` that my data is constantly changing. I want to be able to update the chart dynamically, while I get new `data` from my dummy backend. I am not persisting the data in anyway.

What are your suggestions or recommendations? 
I cannot seem to find a suitable example/tutorial/documentation either.

I know my question is pretty vague, but I hope at least I am the right direction, or that someone can point out how to get there.